# I need help compressing this IF statment down as much as possible in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, int

I have several IF statements that I would like to compress as much as possible so that each time in the array that the number 1 appears it will add 1 to the Ones INT.

```
if (Dice[1] == 1)
{
    Ones ++;
}

if (Dice[2] == 1)
{
    Ones ++;
}

if (Dice[3] == 1)
{
    Ones ++;
}

if (Dice[4] == 1)
{
    Ones ++;
}

if (Dice[5] == 1)
{
    Ones ++;
}
```

Comment: You know that in C++ we normally start at `[0]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're counting `1` values in a sequence and there's a [standard library algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) for that. It takes two iterators and I'm giving it pointers in this case.

```
Ones += std::count(&Dice[1], &Dice[6], 1);
```

This does the same thing and some people might prefer this form.

```
Ones += std::count(Dice + 1, Dice + 6, 1);
```

Comment: This is great and exactly what I needed was able to use this eight times to get the output I needed

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i) if (Dice[i] == 1) Ones++;
```

Or if you prefer a little less straighforward approach that saves a few characters:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i) Ones += (Dice[i] == 1);
```

Would also seem to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Is this any use?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    if(Dice[i]==1)
        Ones++;
}
```